# CA overlay on UISegmentedControl is overwritten in iOS5

Tags: c#, uikit, xamarin.ios, ios5, calayer

I have the following code, which in iOS 4 produces the look of a "disabled" UISegmentedControl. As the attentive reader will notice, I am developing in MonoTouch, thus the c# syntax.

```
private void MakeOverlayOnLastRatingSegment()
{
    RemoveOverlayOnLastRatingSegment();

    lastRatingDisabledLayer = new CALayer();
    lastRatingDisabledLayer.Frame = new RectangleF(new PointF(0, 0), segmLastRating.Frame.Size);

    lastRatingDisabledLayer.CornerRadius = 10.0f;
    lastRatingDisabledLayer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.2f).CGColor;
    segmLastRating.Layer.AddSublayer(lastRatingDisabledLayer);
}
```

And the result is:

[image: Disabled UISegementedControl in iOS4]

But on iOS5 the result is a bit different. The segment before the selected cell is written on top of my gray layer. It takes a bit close look - more evident on a real device instead of simulator. For some reason the screendump from the simulator is very light.

[image: Disabled UISegmentedControl in iOS5]

Has anyone else experienced this, and do somebody have a workaround?

Best regards
/Anders

Comment: have you got answer? i am facing sam eproblem?

Comment: Sadly, my solution became "live with it". It is a very little visibility itch. My conclusion was that hardly any user will observe, even fewer will find it annoying and absolutely nobody will critize the product for having this. So we live with it - but if you do find a solution please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add your overlay layer to the layer of the segmented control’s superview? Or perhaps the segmented control’s layer’s superlayer?